# Leaflet set-up using Nextjs is not working

Tags: next.js, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm currently trying to add a customizable map on my website. But when I try to add [React Leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/start-setup/), the map is visible, but cut in different "leaflet-tiles".
I don't know what is causing this to appear in this particular way.

I'm using Nextjs 13.4.19, react-leaflet 4.2.1 and leaflet 1.9.4.
[image]

I want the map to be in orange block.

## **This is my code :**

```js
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";

export default function Homepage() {
<>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css"
      integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY="
      crossorigin=""
    />
</>;
  return (
    <div className="bg-orange-aggro">
              <MapContainer
                center={[51.505, -0.09]}
                zoom={13}
                scrollWheelZoom={false}
                height="400px"
              >
                <TileLayer
                  attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                  url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                />
                <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
                  <Popup>
                    A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
                  </Popup>
                </Marker>
              </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the documentation :

> If the map is not displayed properly, it is most likely because you haven't followed all the prerequisites.
>
> 1. Make sure all dependencies are installed and using supported versions
> 2. Make sure Leaflet's CSS is loaded
> 3. Make sure your map container has a defined height

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Clement, first of all you have to add this line like Ensar said

Furthermore you need to add your style as object

```
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
.
.
.
    <MapContainer
      center={[51.505, -0.09]}
      zoom={13}
      scrollWheelZoom={false}
      style={{height: '400px'}}
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line of code:

```
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Next.js with app directory, you need to add to your Map component:

```js
    'use client'

    import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
```

And where you want to use it, you need to dynamically import it as:

```js
    import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

    const Map = dynamic(async () => await import('PATH OF MAP COMPONENT'), { ssr: false })
```